# Missing Enumerator in Foreach Loop Editor

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm on a new laptop, working in Visual Studio 2015 on a SQL Server Integration Services package.

In previous versions of Visual Studio there are several options in the Enumerator configuration section, like this...

[image]

In VS 2015, that section is blank and I cannot populate it with a data set.

[image]

I have updated [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) and rebooted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with the Target Server Version in the Project Properties. The new installation of Visual Studio 2015 had it defaulting to vNext. Switching it to SQL Server 2012 caused the configuration to show up.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I resolved the problem by selecting Foreach File Enumerator option under collection. By default under Collections >> Foreach Loop Editor >>> Enumerator was set to foreach Item Enumerator as shown below

[Default Config for Foreach Loop Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiOt1.png)

Instead of "Foreach Item Container" aka the default value, I clicked on it and selected Foreach File Enumerator option and that resolved my problem. Please see snapshot below

[Corrected configuration for Foreach Loop Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q27kS.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem is your visual studio. (below a screenshot of ADo enumerator from my computer , using visual studio 2015)

[image]

- Try running visual studio in safe mode so if this was caused by an add-on it will be fixed. just run this command

  ```
  devenv.exe /safemode
  ```
- If not working Try repairing your SQL Server Data Tools installation or Download the **[Latest release](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks Hadi, safemode is throwing some new and interesting errors I'll go check out and that link you posted is the same one as in my question.

Comment: @TimPeters waiting for ur reply

Comment: Neither /safemode nor the link I posted to SSDT have fixed the issue. I have also tried uninstalling/reinstalling Visual Studio 2015 and got the same results. Oddly enough, when I downloaded a project from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Execute-SQL-Task-and-4aaea562 and opened it in VS2015 I could see the Enumerator Configuration if I switched to ForEach ADO.